Layout of page changes on callback
As the title states, the callbacks change the layout of the page. It's not that it always changes but it does sometimes and I'm not really sure what is causing it.
Upon initial load, the layout is as it should be where you have the graph_content in one row and in the next row having the table_content. However, when changing selector1 or selector2 (which are dropdowns), sometimes table_content is on top of graph_content.
I have:
@callback(
Output('content', 'children'),
Input('stored-data', 'data'),
Input('selector1', 'value'),
Input('selector2', 'value')
)
def content(data, selector1, selector2)
    #some code here to do filter the data

    graph_content = dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(figure = fig_bar, responsive=True), width = 8), 
            dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(figure = fig_tree, responsive=True), width = 4)
        ])
    
    table_content = dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col(
                dash_table.DataTable(
                    columns = [{'groupname': col, 'id': col} for col in ['country', 'size', 'industry']], 
                    data = unique_data.to_dict('records'), 
                    style_cell = {'color': palette.deep_blue}), width = 4)
                ])
    
    content_layout = html.Div([dbc.Row(graph_content), 
                               dbc.Row(table_content)])

    return content_layout
              

                      


Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

better create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run.

TL;DR
Try updating content_layout to:
content_layout = dbc.Container([graph_content, table_content])

Explanation
As stated in the Dash Bootstrap Components documentation:

For best results, make sure you adhere to the following two rules when
constructing your layouts:

Only use Row and Col inside a Container. A single Container wrapping
your entire app's content is fine. [...]
The immediate children of any Row component should
always be Col components. Your content should go inside the Col
components.


The code snippet you posted breaks the two rules above, because:

content_layout wraps a list of dbc.Row directly into an html.Div rather than a dbc.Container.
dbc.Row does not strictly contain dbc.Col objects; graph_content and table_content are already dbc.Row objects, but content_layout wraps them in dbc.Row objects again.

Disclaimer: I could not test that this fixes the layout issue you observed because the code sinppet is not a minimal working example, but I would start by applying those changes to see if they fix your issue.
